# Can physically disabled people participate in the Olympics?

Tags: olympics

E.g. can a person without a hand technically participate 100-metre dash? Was there any precedents(in any sport)?

***NB***: I don't ask about the moral side of the question and don't want to change the judging system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. [Oscar Pistorius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Pistorius) is by far the most famous example, competing in the [men's 400m at the 2012 Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_400_metres). Other examples are [Natalia Partyka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalia_Partyka) who competed in the women's table tennis at the [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_team) and [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_team) Summer Olympics, and [Natalie du Toit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalie_du_Toit) who competed in the [women's 10 km swimming race at the 2008 Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swimming_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_marathon_10_kilometre).

Comment: cool answer, thx!